# jQuery - selecting inside click method

Tags: jquery

Consider the following :-

```
$("#id").click(function(){
// how do i access $("#id") here: say i want to add a class to #id? without $("#id")
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `this` context to access the item selected.

```
$("#id").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("blah");
});
```

Alternatively, each event handler is also passed an event and you can derive the information from that:

```
$("#id").click(function(evt) {
  $(evt.target).addClass("blah");
});
```

See the [jQuery Event object](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event).

I generally favour the approach using `this` however.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).addClass("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [JQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and you will find that you should use `$(this)`.